# chrome inspect blinking with remote debugging

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, debugging, adb

I'm trying to use Chrome's support for remote debugging with my Android device. I've been successful doing this many times, even though it is a bit tricky to setup up.

(I need 'port forwarding' and 'virtual host mapping' so my device can access domain names on my local server.)

## The problem is that (today) chrome://inspect shows the tabs on my device for only a second, then hides them, then shows them again, then hides them...

When Chrome hides all the tabs on my device, the following message appears:

> Pending authentication: please accept debugging session on the device.

### Bad Blink

[image: Pending authentication blink]

### Good Blink

[image: Device tabs blink]

### I see no notification on my device that I can 'accept'.

Even stranger, if I am quick to click on my host, I actually seem to be able to able to use the dev tools for the device like in previous successful situations.

## Why is chrome://inspect blinking and how can I fix it?

### My setup

- Device: Android 5.0 Galaxy S4 for AT&T, with Developer options enabled.
- Device's wifi settings require Proxy, with info for Charles running on host.
- Device connected via USB.
- chrome://inspect has Port Forwarding enabled.
- Chrome: Version 44.0.2403.157 m.
- Android bridge performed by starting Android Studio (version 1.3.1).

Comment: I believe this is the bug report for Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=512150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same behavior here: neither Galaxy S4 nor Galaxy S6 Edge with Lollipop were available on the chrome://inspect tab. I develop an Ionic/Cordova app and downgrade isn't an option. But if you download latest version of [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html) the device is available to inspect and I can debug again.

Comment: Same problem here using Samsung Galaxy S4 and/or adb emulated device on GNU/Linux with Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85. It started failling a few days ago :( i miss my chrome://inspect and really need to debug something!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @SOreadytohelp for the helpful comment.

I borrowed this from the [chromium bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=512150):

> Downgrading Android SDK Platform-tools from revision 23 to revision 21 will solve the issue

Answer (score -2):

You just have to upload your chrome for android, and it will work.

I also came across this problem, but as I updated my chrome for android, the problem got sorted out and now it is working fine.